# Pytest - How to mock or patch global variables

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I have following file and i am running pytests on this file. One of the use case is to test the logger function which is global.  How can we mock this in my pytest ?

```
import spark_fn

def run_job(params):
    do_something()
    logger.info("some info")

def main(params):
    global logger
    app_name = "test app"
    spark, logger = spark_fn(app_name)
    run_job(params)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    params = "some params"
    main(params)


===============================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

How's something like this? You should think of it less like a global variable and more like patching what `spark_fn` is returning to have a "fake" logger class. Also I'm curious how you're using the `spark_fn` module overall with how you're importing it.

```py
import yoursampletest

def test_monkeytest(monkeypatch):
    """
        Monkey patches a fake logger into spark_fn
    """
    class myFakeLogger:

        def info(self, value):
            return value

    def mock_info(mylogstatement):
        return 1, myFakeLogger()

    monkeypatch.setattr(yoursampletest, 'spark_fn', mock_info)

    assert yoursampletest.main(1) == 'some info'
```